# bind_param error

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Error:

> > > Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Jil/benutzer_eintragen.php on line 19

and this is my Code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO benutzer SET vorname='?', nachname='?', username='?', email='?', passwort='?';";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $vorname, $nachname, $username, $email, $passwort);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to eliminate the quote marks in the statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO benutzer SET vorname=?, nachname=?, username=?, email=?, passwort=?;";
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the quotes around the `?` in the SQL statement.

<strike>Also, your SQL statement is incorrect.  `SET` is only used with `UPDATE`, `INSERT` uses `VALUES`.</strike>

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO benutzer(vorname,nachname,username,email,passwort) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
```

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO benutzer SET vorname=?, nachname=?, username=?, email=?, passwort=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $vorname, $nachname, $username, $email, $passwort);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set#861729), the `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax is valid for MySQL.

Comment: @George: I did not know that.  Learn something new every day :-)