# Strange MySQL Error. (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$key = 'blahblah';
$sql = "INSERT INTO softversions SET key='$key'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($mysql_error());
echo "dude";
?>
```

This gives me an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='svksskjfvns'' at line 1
```

The thing is that I've used this script about a hundred times on other pages and it worked.
Table and field names are 100% correct.

I don't understand what is going on.
Do you see the syntax error there?

Comment: Think that should be: `INSERT INTO softversions (key) VALUES ('$key')`

Comment: You use SET for UPDATE statements not INSERT statements. I am very doubtful this script as you have it in the post worked anywhere else..

Comment: @Garvin You can actually use `INSERT INTO .. SET ..`. Here's an old question regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set.

Comment: @Marcus I will have to check this but if what you are saying is correct wouldn't his code work?

Comment: @Garvin He still missed to escape the keyword `key`

Comment: @Marcus I was able to confirm it..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL. To use it as a column, you need to escape it every time you call it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO softversions SET `key`='$key'";
```

Answer (score 2):

`KEY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and you need to escape it  using backticks to use it as a column name and also you should not use `SET` when inserting.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO softversions (`key`) VALUES ('$key')";
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it by 30 secs!

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja Hehe, and I even included a reference to the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = "INSERT INTO softversions(keyName) values('{$key}')";`

Comment: Same error: ...syntax to use near 'key) values('svksskjfvns')' at line 1