# What Have I Done Wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What Have I Done Wrong ?

```
$addedby=$_SESSION['id'];

$text="Subject: I want to add a New Phone Name :$name   Address :$address   Phone :$phone                 Category :$category   Email :$email   Website :$website    Details :$details";
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages SET  text='$text' , from='$addedby'";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Website Under Maintanance '.mysql_error());
```

The Id is integer and the from is `varchar(30)`.

Please Tell Me what have I done wrong ?

The Error Is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from='1'

Comment: As far as I can tell, the thing you've done wrong is that people can't easily figure out what your question actually ***is***.

Comment: Apart from that, the SQL query is syntactically invalid, which would be also apparent from the error message you are getting. Reading [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is kind of a prerequisite for working with anything.

Comment: `from` is a reserved keyword and needs escaping. As @Lawrence Cherone points out in another comment `INSERT into ... SET` is in fact valid in MySQL

Comment: @MartinSmith Yours is the only correct answer ;p

Answer (score 3):

You should try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (`text`,`from`) values ('$text' , '$addedby')";
```

And please note, you should always clean your manual inputs before assembling an SQL query out of them, because SQL injection is very nasty, and makes it very easy to do anything with your DB...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct [**`INSERT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO messages(`text`, `from`) VALUES('$text', '$addedby');
```

**Note that:** Your code this way, is vulnerable for [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) use PDO Or prepared statments instead. See the following post for more information:

- [**Best way to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

`$sql = "INSERT INTO messages SET  text='$text' , from='$addedby'";`

Should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (`text`,`from`) VALUES('$text','$addedby')";
```

And please start using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of Mysql. Its being deprecated.

You should seriously go through some examples and stuff about SQL.

Comment: `INSERT into * SET` is a mysql extension [Prev Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Pointed taken, edited the answer so as to not provide wrong infos! :)

Answer (score 1):

What have you done wrong:

1. You didn't provide enough information to answer the question.
2. You don't use PDO instead of mysql_query.
3. Your SQL is (probably) vulnerable to SQL injection.
4. You use `or die` construct instead of Exceptions.
5. You show the user MySQL error message.
6. You mix syntax of INSERT and UPDATE query.

The query that you want is (provided that $text and $addedby are propertly escaped to prevent SQL injection)

```
INSERT INTO messages (`text`, `from`) VALUES ('$text', '$addedby')
```