# How to use POINT mysql type with mysqli - php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Based on [this table](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) from PHP .net :

```
Type specification chars
Character   Description
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

I write code:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,startLocation) VALUES(?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $day, $startLocation);
```

but problem is becouse my startLocation field in database use type `POINT`, so

How I can make bind_param with POINT dataType in mysql?

Comment: Where can I find the said table on php.net?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: `INSERT INTO days(day,startLocation) VALUES(?, POINT(?, ?)`?

Comment: no, I get error Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in - on that line where is INSERT etc...

Comment: The `bind_param() on a non-object` error means the `prepare()` call already failed, so something is amiss with the SQL statement itself rather than variable types. Check `echo $this->conn->error;` to find out why after attempting to call `prepare()`.

Comment: Please also post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE days` so we can see its structure and types and the contents of the `$day` and `$startLocation` vars.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0U2LfMn.png

Comment: That's part of it -- what do those variables contain? How are you attempting to insert the `POINT` column? What is in the `$startLocation` variable? A single `?` placeholder is probably not going to work because it needs to be inserted via the `POINT()` function.

Comment: Also, we still need to know what the error was `echo $this->conn->error;`

Comment: with string work fine so I will put my coordinates into string

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893691/how-to-insert-point-data-into-mysql-using-pdo-bindparam

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP?

Comment: thanks very much, really nice library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MYSQL function POINT in order to convert from Latitude/Longitude

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,POINT(lat,lon)) VALUES(?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sdd", $day, $lat, $lon);
```