# How to prepare SQL statement with POINT using mysqli when using INSERT

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I can't seem to find where documented to successfully prepare a statement that uses the POINT data type.

This previous question ([How to use POINT mysql type with mysqli - php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323915/how-to-use-point-mysql-type-with-mysqli-php)) shows something marked as correct, but it doesn't work. I even tried using their simple query in their example:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,POINT(lat,lon)) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sdd", $day, $lat, $lon);
```

This just simply returns and error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(lat,lon)) VALUES(?,?,?)' at line 1
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO days(day,point) VALUES(?,POINT(?,?))`!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below;

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,column_name) VALUES(?,POINT(?,?))"); //column_name is name of of column that you want to insert POINT(lat,lon)
    $stmt->bind_param("sdd", $day, $lat, $lon);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :-) I can't believe I couldn't find that documented anywhere