# PHP - Column count doesn't match value count.

Tags: php, mysql

hello this my code.

```
print_r($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo $$key  =  $value;
}

echo $dpopName1= json_encode($_POST['dpopName']);
echo $dpopPosition1= json_encode($_POST['dpopPosition']);
echo $dpopLocation1= json_encode($_POST['dpopLocation']);

    if($sub_cat=='all') {
    $sub_cat='';    
    }

//$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO venders(vender_name, contact_personName,category, subcategory,email,contact_no,address,city,state,pin_code) VALUES ('$vendor_name', '$cont_personName','$cat_type','$sub_cat','$vendor_email', '$contact_no','$vendor_address','$state','$city','$vendor_pin')") or die(mysql_error());
  $insertQuery=mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `venders`(`vender_name`, `vendor_ddNo`, `vendor_ddDate`,     `vendor_regid`, `dateCorp`, `contact_personName`, `category`, `subcategory`, `email`, `contact_no`, `fax_no`,      `website`, `address`, `city`, `taluka`, `state`, `pin_code`, `vendor_Baddress`, `Bstate`, `Bcity`, `Bvendor_pin`,      `Btaluka`, `Bcontact_no`, `Bfax_no`, `Bvendor_email`, `Bwebsite`, `govtUndertake`, `stateUndertake`, `publiclCompany`,      `privatelCompany`, `copSociaty`, `partnerFirm`, `propritorship`, `anyOtherspecify`, `dpopName`, `dpopPosition`,       `dpopLocation`, `panDetails`, `panRequireFor`, `serviceTaxregDetails`, `serviceTaxrequiredFor`, `pfRegisterDetails`,       `pfRequireFor`, `excDutyreg`, `excRequireFor`, `labourLicensedetails`, `licencePanrequireFor`, `stvRegNo`,       `stvRequireFor`, `stvregDateDetails`, `stvregDateRequiredFor`, `orgStrngth`, `NameofCompany`, `NameofBank`,       
     `nameOfbankBranch`, `cityofMB`, `accountNo`, `accountType`, `bankBranchIfsccode`, `micodeofBankbranch`,       `otherBankerDetails`) 
     VALUES ('$vendor_name','$vendor_ddNo','$vendor_ddDate','$vendor_id','$dateCorp','$cont_personName','$vendor_address',      '$cat_type','$sub_cat','$vendor_email','$contact_no','$fax_no','$website','$vendor_address','$city','$taluka','$state','$vendor_pin',      '$vendor_Baddress','$Bstate','$Bcity','$Bvendor_pin','$Btaluka','$Bcontact_no','$Bfax_no','$Bvendor_email','$Bwebsite','$govtUndertake',      '$stateUndertake', '$publiclCompany',      '$privatelCompany', '$copSociaty', '$partnerFirm', '$propritorship', '$anyOtherspecify', '$dpopName1', '$dpopPosition1',       '$dpopLocation1','$panDetails', '$panRequireFor', '$serviceTaxregDetails', '$serviceTaxrequiredFor', '$pfRegisterDetails',       '$pfRequireFor', '$excDutyreg', '$excRequireFor', '$labourLicensedetails', '$licencePanrequireFor', '$stvRegNo',       
     '$stvRequireFor', '$stvregDateDetails', '$stvregDateRequiredFor', '$orgStrngth', '$NameofCompany', '$NameofBank',       '$nameOfbankBranch', '$cityofMB', '$accountNo', '$accountType', '$bankBranchIfsccode', '$micrCodeofBankbranch',       '$otherBankerDetails'
    )")  or die(mysql_error());
```

1. Array to string conversion error
2. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

I tried following to solve the prooblem:

1. for solving 1st error i use json encode to convert the array into json string then i place the json string variable into insert table.
2. for column count error i checked wheather my database id has a primary key or not and it has a primary key then also i count all the value and column and also i cross check all the syntax but i found nothing.

Comment: Count the number of columns and values. They are ***not*** the same. Also, there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @AmalMurali thanks for the replay but i have already count all the values and column and that is correct.

Comment: Okay, is there a secret command that can generate the above text provided by @Amal Murali. I swear I see that text word for word all across the cluster here.

Comment: try to check (and see error) on smaller query, no need to show here 'all code you got' =\ also you can recheck your query in mysql IDE (or pma) to get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your variables would contain a `'` that would destroy your query.

Sure it would be best to use [DBO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), but since I guess you are trying to implement something here into existing code, you should try to debug this more:

```
print_r($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo $$key  =  mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

echo $dpopName1= mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($_POST['dpopName']));
echo $dpopPosition1= mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($_POST['dpopPosition']));
echo $dpopLocation1= mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($_POST['dpopLocation']));
```

---

debug with:

```
$query="INSERT IGNORE INTO `venders`(`vender_name`, `vendor_ddNo`, `vendor_ddDate`, `vendor_regid`, `dateCorp`, `contact_personName`, `category`, `subcategory`, `email`, `contact_no`, `fax_no`, `website`, `address`, `city`, `taluka`, `state`, `pin_code`, `vendor_Baddress`, `Bstate`, `Bcity`, `Bvendor_pin`, `Btaluka`, `Bcontact_no`, `Bfax_no`, `Bvendor_email`, `Bwebsite`, `govtUndertake`, `stateUndertake`, `publiclCompany`, `privatelCompany`, `copSociaty`, `partnerFirm`, `propritorship`, `anyOtherspecify`, `dpopName`, `dpopPosition`, `dpopLocation`, `panDetails`, `panRequireFor`, `serviceTaxregDetails`, `serviceTaxrequiredFor`, `pfRegisterDetails`, `pfRequireFor`, `excDutyreg`, `excRequireFor`, `labourLicensedetails`, `licencePanrequireFor`, `stvRegNo`, `stvRequireFor`, `stvregDateDetails`, `stvregDateRequiredFor`, `orgStrngth`, `NameofCompany`, `NameofBank`, `nameOfbankBranch`, `cityofMB`, `accountNo`, `accountType`, `bankBranchIfsccode`, `micrCodeofBankbranch`, `otherBankerDetails`) VALUES ('$vendor_name','$vendor_ddNo','$vendor_ddDate','$vendor_id','$dateCorp','$cont_personName','$vendor_address', '$cat_type','$sub_cat','$vendor_email','$contact_no','$fax_no','$website','$vendor_address','$city','$taluka','$state','$vendor_pin', '$vendor_Baddress','$Bstate','$Bcity','$Bvendor_pin','$Btaluka','$Bcontact_no','$Bfax_no','$Bvendor_email','$Bwebsite','$govtUndertake', '$stateUndertake', '$publiclCompany', '$privatelCompany', '$copSociaty', '$partnerFirm', '$propritorship', '$anyOtherspecify', '$dpopName1', '$dpopPosition1', '$dpopLocation1','$panDetails', '$panRequireFor', '$serviceTaxregDetails', '$serviceTaxrequiredFor', '$pfRegisterDetails', '$pfRequireFor', '$excDutyreg', '$excRequireFor', '$labourLicensedetails', '$licencePanrequireFor', '$stvRegNo', '$stvRequireFor', '$stvregDateDetails', '$stvregDateRequiredFor', '$orgStrngth', '$NameofCompany', '$NameofBank', '$nameOfbankBranch', '$cityofMB', '$accountNo', '$accountType', '$bankBranchIfsccode', '$micrCodeofBankbranch', '$otherBankerDetails')";

if (!$insertQuery=mysql_query($query)){
  echo $query;
  die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay. i have checked the syntax if find any then please tell me.

Comment: sorry i am not getting what you are saying. would you please put the code or clarify please thank you

Comment: so what's the outcome of echo query? can you post it on pastebin?

Answer (score 3):

A better way... to insert, when you're inserting alot of columns is... to use [`INSERT INTO SET`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set), because then you have a better idea of which columns are missing.. than meticulously going through your mapped INSERT, and checking whether you have every column to every value.

```
INSERT INTO sometable
   SET field1 = 'value1',
       field2 = 'value2',
       field3 = 'value3'
```

([Milov](http://milov.nl/2836), 2004).

It also helps, to [escape](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) every single value that you are inserting (But keep in mind... it is recommended to use [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) over MySQL Real Escape).

Comment: +1 ... wow, I'm glad I woke up this morning to be able to learn this.

Answer (score -3):

I notice this small mistake: 
You use

> `

instead of

> '

which is totally wrong.