# how to run sql query when !empty($_POST[' ']) is true?

Tags: php, mysql, post

The result of the block of code below is always "d=0".I dont understand why?

```
 if (!empty($_POST["transactionid"])) {

     $sql_set = "SET timestamp = '$timestamp',";
     $sql = "INSERT INTO phpclassifieds_payments
                $sql_set
                txnid = '$trnxid',
                adid  = '$adid',
                adtype = 'A',
                amountpaid ='$amount_paid'";

     $tx = mysql_query($sql);
     if ($tx) {
         $d = 1;
     } else {
         $d = 0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: mind checking for `mysql_error()` first?

Comment: Just go backwards. See where `$d` gets its value and look up in the manual why.

Comment: Obligatory mysql_* is depricated, use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Your query is wrong. You cant use SET in INSERT query.

Comment: INSERT INTO and SET is not query compatible.

Comment: @Nitin and Logan thats wrong, you can use `SET` with `INSERT` for `MySQL`

Comment: But syntactically his query is wrong. He should use VALUES in INSERT query.

Comment: No thats another invalid command. Thats fine syntax. That query is not wrong due to that reason.

Comment: I am using  this block of code  in making REST API. I have to pass data in json(one of which is transactionid) and see its output. I am using Advanced Rest CLient Apllication and Postman to do so. How can i check for mysql_error()??

Comment: All that Rest and Client stuff is irrelevant to this question. Simply do this      `$tx = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See : [MySQL INSERT INTO table VALUES.. vs INSERT INTO table SET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set)

Are you sure that your [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_DBMS) allow the `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax ?

Maybe change it to :

```sql
INSERT INTO phpclassifieds_payments VALUES ('val 1', 'val 2', ...);
```

Try to debug it with :

```
$d = 0;
die('error sql : ' . mysql_error());
```

If mysql_error, it doesn't return any value try `echo $sql;` to see your sql query.

Comment: Their DBMS, as stated, is MySQL, which clearly allows for both those.

Comment: I am using  this block of code  in making REST API. I have to pass data in json(one of which is transactionid) and see its output. I am using Advanced Rest CLient Apllication and Postman to do so. How can i check for mysql_error()??

Answer (score 0):

You must check have any bugs in your queries by using

```
echo "<pre>".mysql_error()."</pre>"
```

It'll returns the mysql error information of query just before processed.

You must also ensure that their is a space between your table name and SET statement,

just rewrite `$sql_set = " SET timestamp = '$timestamp', ";`

Otherwise your joined query string is

```
INSERT INTO phpclassifieds_paymentsSET timestamp = '$timestamp',
                txnid = '$trnxid',
                adid  = '$adid',
                adtype = 'A',
                amountpaid ='$amount_paid'
```