# MySQL INSERT Syntax error and unsure why

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im getting the following error with my query from PHP:

Does anyone have any ideas on why? its passing an email address and from error looks like its breaking there but i might be wrong.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO customers SET
>                 name = "James Brandon",
>                 email = "james@ambient' at line 10

PHP

```
$query .= "INSERT INTO customers SET
                name = '".$customer_name."',
                email = '".$customer_email."',
                address_1 = '".$customer_address_1."',
                address_2 = '".$customer_address_2."',
                town = '".$customer_town."',
                county = '".$customer_county."',
                postcode = '".$customer_postcode."',
                phone = '".$customer_phone."',

                name_ship = '".$customer_name_ship."',
                address_1_ship = '".$customer_address_1_ship."',
                address_2_ship = '".$customer_address_2_ship."',
                town_ship = '".$customer_town_ship."',
                county_ship = '".$customer_county_ship."',
                postcode_ship = '".$customer_postcode_ship."';
            ";
```

Comment: you are appending insert query in `$query` which is wrong

Comment: Maybe you have mixed `INSERT` and `UPDATE` syntaxes?

Comment: you have written wrong syntax for insert -- INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Comment: And please, please, please, stop throwing out all this code vulnerable to [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which is so nice and simple to use, your code will even be shorter and cleaner!

Comment: @sanirranta this is not the wrong syntax it is MySQL's extension. reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set

Comment: Did you see @James that there is a double quote at the error message in the email?

Comment: I did not, however i rewrote and getting a syntax error after the email now here: https://shrib.com/SZyBXpxN (any ideas?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible syntax for INSERT statement.
In the first following case, you specify only col you want to fill.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3)
VALUES (VAL_COL1, VAL_COL2, VAL_COL3);
```

You can also INSERT without providing col_name but you will have to specify value of all columns and in the **good order**.

The first opton is better in my opinion and will avoid you many mistakes especially when you have a lot of different column in your table.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp), you should try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO customers (name , email, address_1, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments to your answer, please [consider using PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php). It is much safer and in my opinion even easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

@James Since you are doing INSERT command. Do as the following.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers (name, email, address_1, address_2, town, county, postcode, phone, name_ship, address_1_ship, address_2_ship, town_ship, county_ship, postcode_ship) VALUES('".$customer_name."', '".$customer_email."', '".$customer_address_1."', '".$customer_address_2."', '".$customer_town."', '".$customer_county."', '".$customer_postcode."', '".$customer_phone."', '".$customer_name_ship."', '".$customer_address_1_ship."', '".$customer_address_2_ship."', '".$customer_town_ship."', '".$customer_county_ship."', '".$customer_postcode_ship."')";
```

Thanks & Regards,

**Vivek**

Comment: Thanks, seems im getting a syntax issue with date and / any ideas? https://shrib.com/SZyBXpxN

Comment: can you please post little eloborate PHP script & Error message which will be useful to help you. And also given URL link is not working.

Comment: As per I reviewed your code. I'm not getting any syntax errors. Only thing we need to consider is whether this foreach and post variables are inside this if condition.


`if (isset($_POST['invoice_product'])) { //validates whether form is submitted or not.
    foreach ($_POST['invoice_product'] as $key => $value) { // invoice product items
        //your code goes here.
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you don't need to append that

> ; in between your mysql query

your modified query will be

```
 $query =      "INSERT INTO customers SET name = '".$customer_name."',

                  email = '".$customer_email."',

                  address_1 = '".$customer_address_1."',

                  address_2 = '".$customer_address_2."',

                  town = '".$customer_town."',

                  county = '".$customer_county."',

                  postcode = '".$customer_postcode."',

                  phone = '".$customer_phone."',

                  name_ship = '".$customer_name_ship."',

                  address_1_ship = '".$customer_address_1_ship."',

                  address_2_ship = '".$customer_address_2_ship."',

                  town_ship = '".$customer_town_ship."',

                  county_ship = '".$customer_county_ship."',

                  postcode_ship = '".$customer_postcode_ship."'
            ";
```

Please note there is a

> semi-colon after `$customer_postcode_ship` and no need of the `.` in `$query`