# Use last inserted id to insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
<?php   
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO customer SET email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "'");
?>
```

And after this i need to make an INSERT to another table like this:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO order SET customer_id = '" . //here goes the id i need from previous query ."'";
```

In my customer table i have only one auto-increment column called customer_id and after first insertion to this table i need to get this customer_id value and use it to the next insertion (to order table).

How can i do this? I read about

```
$mysqli->insert_id
```

but all the examples connect to a database whereas i am already connected to database and run queries with this->db. Any help about syntax or other solution is really appreciated!

Comment: you realize that you're using a mysql reserved word.

Comment: ...and is most likely why your code failed.

Comment: [Always make the Manual  your best Friend](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I doubt he does realize that.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I won't take any chances.

Comment: @StavrosB You have answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below code you can get the last inserted id, so you need use it after your 1st insert and before your 2nd insert.

```
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

An example would be:

```
<?php   
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO customer (email) values ('".$this->db->escape($data['email']."')";
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `order` (customer_id) values ({$insert_id})";
?>
```

$insert_id is an integer, so you dont need to escape it again.
order is a reserved word though, so you might want to change your table name.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the last insert id as follows..

```
<?php
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO customer SET email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "'");    
$id=$this->db->insert_id();
?>
```

Normally the insert_id() function returns the last inserted id in an auto-incrementing Mysql column.
It will work most of the time but for that one instance where it is not working, you will be lucky to find out in time(like I did)

```
$this->db->insert(table_name, $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

In the event that it malfunctions, the quick-fix is to go raw, like below:

```
$this->db->insert(table_name, $data);
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$row = $query->row_array();
return $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your insert query is wrong, so used below code

```
 <?php   
    $query = "INSERT INTO customer ( email ) VALUES ('" .$this->db->escape($data['email']) . "')";
    $this->db->query($query );
    $id=$this->db->insert_id();
    ?>
```

Comment: [Insert SET VS Insert Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set)