# With insert SET syntax can I insert multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have read in the [Using The INSERT INTO ... SET Syntax In MySQL](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2913-using-the-insert-into-set-syntax-in-mysql.htm) blog, that you can use the following `SET` syntax  to insert records.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET col1= 'val1', col6= 'val6', col10='val10';
INSERT INTO mytable SET col3= 'val3', col5= 'val5', col10='val10';
INSERT INTO mytable SET col4= 'val4', col5= 'val5', col6='val6';
```

Is it possible to insert multiple rows with only 1 statement?

Comment: or [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6889065/5292302)

Comment: this is not duplicate question,i don't want to use another approach i.e. insert into (col_names) values (..),(..) because i have 10 columns in my table and records values (which i want to insert) are varied ie. in 1st record v1,v2, only in 2nd record v3 v4 only

Comment: sir petter, https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2913-using-the-insert-into-set-syntax-in-mysql.htm , we can insert using 'set' also

Comment: You need to clarify your question, that it's this exact syntax you like as you have seen people taught your question was about inserting multiple rows.

Comment: I have done an edit to your question, lets see if it gets reopen, anyway the answer to your question is probably no, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html, there seems to be no syntaxt to add multiple rows.

Comment: I assume you'd want this so that if one fails, the others aren't inserted. If so, then using a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) with a rollback could solve that problem.  But that MySql specific `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax just isn't designed for multiple inserts.

Answer (score 5):

No, the `INSERT ... SET` syntax cannot be used to insert multiple rows. If you look at the `INSERT ... SET` syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) you'll see:

> ```
> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
>     [INTO] tbl_name
>     [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
>     SET assignment_list
>     [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]
> ```

Alongside:

> ```
> assignment:
>     col_name = value
>
> assignment_list:
>     assignment [, assignment] ...
> ```

Only 1 `assignment_list` (list of values) can be provided, hence you can only insert one row.

This is also indicated on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set#comment14334276_861729) on a question asking about the differences between `INSERT ... SET` and `INSERT ... VALUES`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `insert into select ...`.

```
insert into tbl1 (col1, col2, col3)
   select equivalent_col1, equivalent_col2, equivalent_col3 from tbl2 
     where filterCol = 1;
```

The above query fetches data from tbl2 and insert into tbl1

Comment: simonare sir,sorry,i want to know and use insert into 'set' query,i don't want to use another approach i.e. insert into (col_names) values (..),(..) because i have 10 columns in my table and records values (which i want to insert) are varied ie. in 1st record v1,v2, only in 2nd record v3 v4 only

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. does @Sibert's solution works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
CREATE TABLE co
    (coid int, name varchar(30));
INSERT INTO co
    (coid, name)
VALUES
    (1,'Volvo'),
    (2,'BMW'),
    (3,'Microsoft'),
    (4,'Apple')
;
```

You can also shorten this (exact value positions):

```
INSERT INTO co
VALUES
    (1,'Volvo'),
    (2,'BMW'),
    (3,'Microsoft'),
    (4,'Apple')
;
```

Comment: sibert,i am sorry,i want to know and use insert into 'set' query,i don't want to use another approach i.e. insert into (col_names) values (..),(..) because i have 10 columns in my table and records values (which i want to insert) are varied ie. in 1st record v1,v2, only in 2nd record v3 v4 only

Comment: Never heard of set. But it sounds like "UPSERT". Insert OR update values.

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT INTO ... SET ...` syntax can't be used for multiple inserts with the same statement.

But you could use an `INSERT INTO` from a `SELECT` with `UNION ALL` instead.
Or an `INSERT INTO` from `VALUES`.

And then put NULL in the columns that don't have a value.

**Example:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable
> (
>   id int primary key auto_increment,
>   col1 varchar(30),
>   col2 varchar(30),
>   col3 varchar(30),
>   col4 varchar(30),
>   col5 varchar(30)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
> SELECT 'val1' as val1, null as val2, null as val3, 'val4' as val4, null as val5
> UNION ALL SELECT null, 'val2', null, null, null
> UNION ALL SELECT 'val1', null, 'val3', null, 'val5';
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES 
> (null, 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', null),
> ('val1', null, 'val3', null, 'val5');
> ```

> ```
> select * from mytable;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
> -: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
>  1 | val1 | null | null | val4 | null
>  2 | null | val2 | null | null | null
>  3 | val1 | null | val3 | null | val5
>  4 | null | val2 | val3 | val4 | null
>  5 | val1 | null | val3 | null | val5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d07b9f56c5f4aa5c56c96792729e1370)*

Answer (score -1):

To add multiple rows into a table using a single INSERT statement, you use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
  ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
VALUES
  ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Billy', 125, 'London Office'),
  ('Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
```

Comment: sir i am sorry,i want to know and use insert into 'set' query,i don't want to use another approach i.e. insert into (col_names) values (..),(..) because i have 10 columns in my table and records values (which i want to insert) are varied ie. in 1st record v1,v2, only in 2nd record v3 v4 only