# Pdo insert query in for loop

Tags: php, pdo, insert

Where am i doing wrong ? Count($sepetler) => 2 row.İts ok.Not problem here values key in variables truth not problem here.But not working exec.All of code here.I trust to $sepet array and variables but.İnsert statement is problem.Please help me for find eror

```
    $dbConfig=new DBConfig();
    $baglanti = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbConfig->host.";dbname=".$dbConfig->dbname, $dbConfig->dbuser, $dbConfig->password);
    $baglanti->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $baglanti->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $siparis_kodu=$post["merchant_oid"];
    $sepetGetirSql = "select * from sepetler where siparis_kodu='".$siparis_kodu."'";
    //
    $sepetler = array();


  $queryResultSepetList = $baglanti->query( $sepetGetirSql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
  if ( $queryResultSepetList->rowCount() > 0 ) {
      foreach ( $queryResultSepetList as $row ) {
          array_push( $sepetler, $row );
        }
      }
            $sepet_say=count($sepetler);


            for ($i=0; $i <count($sepetler) ; $i++) {
                $statement = $baglanti->prepare("SELECT urun_adi,urun_fiyati FROM urunler WHERE urun_id = :urun_id");
                $statement->execute(array( ":urun_id" => $sepetler[0]["urun_id"] ));
                $urun_bilgileri = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $query = $baglanti->prepare("INSERT INTO siparisler SET
                  urun_id = ?,
                  miktar = ?,
                  urun_fiyati = ?,
                  siparis_kodu = ?,
                  kargo_takip_no = ?,
                  odeme_durumu = ?,
                  uye_id = ?");
                  $insert = $query->execute(array(
                    $sepetler[$i]["urun_id"], $sepetler[$i]["miktar"], $urun_bilgileri["urun_fiyati"],$sepetler[$i]["siparis_kodu"],"",0,$sepetler[$i]["uye_id"]
                  ));
                  $mesaj="başarılı sipariş";
              }
```

Comment: There might be a syntax error in your query if you didn't enclose strings with a delimiter. That said, this would be easier if you used prepared statement which is not the case here and makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Please do some proper error handling (check your error log, config PDO to throw exceptions on errors) to see what it complaints about. But as @AymDev dev says, use prepared statements with placeholders instead of injecting data directly into your queries like that. It's way more error prone and insecure to do it the way you're currently doing it.

Comment: I'm edited code.Please help me friends

Comment: You always fetch with `$sepetler[0]["urun_id"]` inside the loop, should this be `$sepetler[$i]["urun_id"]` (with `$i`) to pick up the relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the UPDATE syntax for an INSERT statement.

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

or if you are filling all of the columns in order then you can shorten it to:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: But pdo using this insert system.Your answer is using sql and mysql

Comment: Even with PDO I have not found anywhere using this syntax

Comment: https://masterdark.net/pdo-kullanimi/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set

Comment: Both formats are valid for an insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $prepare = $baglanti->prepare("INSERT INTO siparisler SET urun_id = :urun_id,miktar=:miktar,urun_fiyati=:urun_fiyati,siparis_kodu=:siparis_kodu,kargo_takip_no=:kargo_takip_no,odeme_durumu=:odeme_durumu,uye_id=:uye_id");

  $veriler = [
      "urun_id" =>  $sepetler[$i]["urun_id"],
      "miktar" =>  $sepetler[$i]["miktar"],
      "urun_fiyati" =>  $urun_bilgileri["urun_fiyati"],
      "siparis_kodu" =>  $sepetler[$i]["siparis_kodu"],
      "kargo_takip_no" =>  "",
      "odeme_durumu" => 1,
      "uye_id" => $sepetler[$i]["uye_id"]
  ];
  // verileri çalıştır
  $prepare->execute($veriler);
```

İt's working for me.Problem is fixed.Thank you all of them